# The js registration form validation not working

Tags: javascript

I am performing javascript form validation for my registration form. But even if I do not meet the conditions of js validation data is getting stored in database.

I looked at some of the previous answers to the question in the stack overflow but did not get the expected output.

Javascript code:

```
function validateform() {
  var uname = document.myform.uname.value;
  var password = document.myform.password.value;
  var repassword = document.myform.repassword.value;
  var email = document.myform.email.value;
  var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= x.length) {
    alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address \n atpostion:" + atposition + "\n dotposition:" + dotposition);
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (uname == null || uname == "") {
    alert("Name can't be blank");
    uname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (password.length < 6) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
    password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (password != repassword) {
    alert("password must be same!");
    repassword.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform"  onSubmit="return 
validateform()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required>
  <br>
  <input type="email" placeholder="EmailID" name="email" required>
  <br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
  <br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Re-Type Password" name="repassword" required>
  <br>
  <input type="date" name="date">
  <p>Gender:</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"> 
</form>
```

Please help me rectify the problem.

Comment: `document.myform.uname.value;` . How is the script supposed to know if `myform` is an `ID` or a `class` or a `name` ?  Same goes for the element `uname`.  Unless you're using a JS library that we can't see?  The "normal" way I've always done this is by `ID` . Like so --> `<input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="Username" name="uname">`  And get it's value like: `var uname = document.getElementById("UserName").value`

Comment: Ok! i'll try that